# how do i delay binding a event in backbone.js until after a certian time?

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, backbone-events

```
app.myView = Backbone.View.extend({
   events: {
   'mouseenter .myitem': 'myfunction'
   }    
});
```

how do i delay this event from being created until a certain time or until I decide that i'd like to create it.   right now it is created as soon as my view is loading in and the mouseevent is triggering as soon as I enter .myitem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone binds view events using `delegateEvents`:

> **delegateEvents** `delegateEvents([events])`
>
> Uses jQuery's `on` function to provide declarative callbacks for DOM events within a view. If an **events** hash is not passed directly, uses `this.events` as the source.
>   [...]
>   When **delegateEvents** is run again, perhaps with a different `events` hash, all callbacks are removed and delegated afresh — useful for views which need to behave differently when in different modes.

You can call `delegateEvents` whenever you want to change the event bindings. So one way to do this would be to adjust `this.events` and call `this.delegateEvents()`:

```
add_event: function() {
    this.events = _({}).extend(this.events, {
        'mouseenter .myitem': 'myfunction'
    });
    this.delegateEvents();
}
```

The [`extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) call is a good idea because `Backbone.View.extend` will leave the `events` attached the view's prototype so simply changing `this.events`:

```
this.events['mouseenter .myitem'] = 'myfunction';
```

would alter the `events` for all instances of the view. The advantage of this is that calling [`undelegateEvents`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-undelegateEvents) will do the Right Thing and all your view events will be handled the same way.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Bd4SB/

Comment: Thank you for this.  It worked. I am going to use the extend method you provided!

Answer (score 2):

you can always create it manually (using the `events` object is just a shortcut):

```
// call this somewhere once you're ready to attach the callback method    
this.$el.on(eventName, _.bind(method, this));
```

Or with your example:

```
this.$el.on('mouseenter .myitem', _.bind(this.myfunction, this));
```

Comment: I've added an example for your case. hope it helps.

Comment: this works so kudos for this but I believe mu is too short has the better answer.  Thank you for helping me.